# What do you name a protocol for ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: mvvm

So we have an app using MVVM architecture and we call view models like XViewModel (eg DatasetViewModel), views XViewController (eg DatasetViewController).
However we don’t know what to name the protocol the XViewModelImplements.

Comment: In my cases protocol used by view models are named like XViewModelProtocol. It is more of an personal choice in this case.

Comment: yeah, thinking about that, or 2. having a protocol XViewModel and then class DefaultXViewModel, MockXViewModel,...